# WebGL Perspective Projection

Tags: webgl

I have a scene of a cube with vertices defined like so

```
const positions = [
    -10.0,  10.0,
     10.0,  10.0,
    -10.0, -10.0,
     10.0, -10.0
  ];
```

I'm trying to go from a field of view perspective matrix (not shown) to a specified rectangle perspective projection matrix defined like so

```
const n = 0.1;
const f = 100.0;
const l = -50;
const r = 50;
const t = 50;
const b = -50;

Float32Array([
      (2*n/r-l),       0.0,          0.0,  0.0,
            0.0, (2*n/t-b),          0.0,  0.0,
      (r+l/r-l), (t+b/t-b),   -(f+n/f-n), -1.0,
            0.0,       0.0, -(2*f*n/f-n),  0.0
    ]);
```

I also have a model matrix that moves the box `-6` units in the z index so that it's within the bounds of the near and far clip planes.

Am I right to assume that before transforming anything the coordinates I use to specify the box and perspective matrix are in the same space/frame of reference? Therefore the box should be dead center of the view?

The box renders with the field of view matrix, but not the matrix defined above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formulas are not exact. Try this (I have added parentheses only):

```
Float32Array([
      (2*n)/(r-l),         0.0,            0.0,  0.0,
              0.0, (2*n)/(t-b),            0.0,  0.0,
      (r+l)/(r-l), (t+b)/(t-b),   -(f+n)/(f-n), -1.0,
              0.0,         0.0, -(2*f*n)/(f-n),  0.0
    ]);
```

Comment: Oh wow, so I was essentially coming unstuck do to operator precedence! I was thinking `2n/r-l` was being interpreted like `(2 * n) / (r - l)` when in fact it was being interpreted like `((2 * n) / r) -l)`. Thanks